# I have 2 objects with similiar properties, can I use send like this safely?

Tags: ruby

```
if ...
  o = User
elseif ...
  o = Car


o.send(:count) = 100
o.send(:is_high) = true

o.save!
```

I want to reduce the duplicate code, is this ok to do?

I will have tests for this in case property names change etc.

Comment: You should have stated why you thought this wouldn't work.

Comment: BTW, the ruby code you supply isn't valid, eg elseif.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing `o.send(:count) = 100` will give you a syntax error so presumably you really mean this:

```
o.send(:count=, 100)
o.send(:is_high=, true)
```

Yes, that's fine but will leave the people maintaining your code scratching their heads and wondering why didn't just do this:

```
o.count   = 100
o.is_high = true
```

You usually only use [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000999) when you don't know the method name until run time:

```
m = want_pancakes ? :pancakes : :eggs
o.send(m, true)
```

Answer (score 1):

No that is not OK because the `:count` getter method is different from the `:count=` setter method.  You could do this:

```
o.send(:count=, 100)
```

Ruby is a dynamically typed language.  You don't need to use `send`, you can just call the methods directly:

```
o = if ...
  User
elsif ...
  Car
end

o.count = 100
o.is_high = true
o.save!
```